# string replace function for encryption algorithm not working properly?

Tags: c++, string, encryption, replace, substitution

I'm trying to make a simple letter substitution encryption program, but the during the encryption process, It somehow doesn't work properly. please tell me what is wrong with the code. The jist of the code below is that it asks for an input, and then it sends the input to the ReplaceLowercase function, which looks at each letter until it finds the corresponding letter in the input string, and then substitutes it with the 17 character string defined in the first part, and then moves on to encrypt the next letter.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string ReplaceLowercase(string input){
    string A = "7W^S;/vB(6%I|w[fl";
    string B = "<w7>4f//Z55ZxK'z.";
    string C = "_W5g(lu<pTu3^_A7n";
    string D = "OfLm%8:EF}0V1?BSS";
    string E = "|+E6t;AZ~XewXP17T";
    string F = "L-nIbhm5<z:92~+;x";
    string G = "L-nIbhm5<z:92~+;x";
    string H = "9bC5f0q@qA(RKZ>|r";
    string I = "9bC5f0q@qA(RKZ>|r";
    string J = "k=5;ln(08IAl(gGAK";
    string K = "|N;8]dGu)'^MaYpu[";
    string L = "!&;Y*nz8C*;J}{+d]";
    string M = "Us9%^%?n5!~e@@*+@";
    string N = "zF8,1KV#¥]$k?|9R#";
    string O = "0B4>=nioEjp>4rhgi";
    string P = "EG@0[W9.N4i~E<f3x";
    string Q = "(0Pwkk&IPchJHs.7A";
    string R = "7XgmQ6fW<|J+NY[m0";
    string S = ".g4CwX/DU!!~!zbtZ";
    string T = "+_U'qn_/9Fo|gT/!n";
    string U = "=0s(mYh&F%y=MBS5(";
    string V = "cg71(}bo+Q5P8F[T6";
    string W = "lc|a\%5.9pOpooU+QR";
    string X = "E_(3A:o+.]qL3MYA6";
    string Y = "H@O'X_RiVS@8l0bKD";
    string Z = "Y1gbGD`~8d>HSWN35";
    

    int n = input.find("a",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,A.size(),A); 
        n=input.find("a",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("b",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,B.size(),B); 
        n=input.find("b",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("c",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,C.size(),C); 
        n=input.find("c",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("d",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,D.size(),D); 
        n=input.find("d",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("e",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,E.size(),E); 
        n=input.find("e",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("f",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,F.size(),F); 
        n=input.find("f",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("g",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,G.size(),G); 
        n=input.find("g",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("h",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,H.size(),H); 
        n=input.find("h",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("i",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,I.size(),I); 
        n=input.find("i",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("j",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,J.size(),J); 
        n=input.find("J",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("k",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,K.size(),K); 
        n=input.find("k",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("l",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,L.size(),L); 
        n=input.find("l",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("m",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,M.size(),M); 
        n=input.find("m",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("n",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,N.size(),N); 
        n=input.find("n",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("o",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,O.size(),O); 
        n=input.find("o",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("p",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,P.size(),P); 
        n=input.find("p",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("q",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,Q.size(),Q); 
        n=input.find("q",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("r",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,R.size(),R); 
        n=input.find("r",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("s",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,S.size(),S); 
        n=input.find("s",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("t",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,T.size(),T); 
        n=input.find("t",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("u",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,U.size(),U); 
        n=input.find("u",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("v",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,V.size(),V); 
        n=input.find("v",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("w",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,W.size(),W); 
        n=input.find("w",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("x",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,X.size(),W); 
        n=input.find("x",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("y",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,Y.size(),Y); 
        n=input.find("y",n+17);
    }

    n =input.find("z",0);
    while(n < input.length()){
        input.replace(n,Z.size(),Z); 
        n=input.find("z",n+17);
    }
    return input;
}

int main(){
    string input;
    cin >> input;
    input = ReplaceLowercase(input);
    cout << input << std::endl;
    cout << "encryption complete" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Unless you're targeting some esoteric system, then you could assume ASCII in which the letters are contiguously encoded. Which means all of your code could be replaced by a loop from `'a'` to `'z'` together with an array for the string replacements.

Comment: W.size() is not 17

Comment: where are you checking to see if `find` returns -1 ?

Comment: Why convert the pos to int instead of just using the type returned by `find`? `auto n = input.find(...);` `std:string::npos` is very likely not representable in `int`; you'll likely end up with a negative value instead of a positive one.

Comment: `"lc|a\%5.9pOpooU+QR"` looks invalid, I;d expect `"lc|a\\%5.9pOpooU+QR"`.

Comment: *"please tell me what is wrong with the code."* -- please tell what is wrong with the functionality of this code. (The current description, "somehow doesn't work properly", is useless as a problem description.) What did you observe that led you to the conclusion that there is something wrong with the code? Can you demonstrate this particular malfunction with simpler code, a [mre]? (You need to code for each letter in your program, but do you need all of that to demonstrate the problem? Could you make use of a `\\ And so on...` comment?)

Comment: @PatrickParker It could be that `W.size()` is 17. It appears to be [implementation-defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) how `"\%"` is interpreted. The compiler I tried it on converted that to `"%"`, making the size of `W` 17.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code above will substitue letters that were already substituted
that is, after 'a' is replaced, replacing 'b' will go over 'a' substitue
and replace any 'b', i kept it that way

```
string Subs[]=
{
    "7W^S;/vB(6%I|w[fl",
    "<w7>4f//Z55ZxK'z.",
    "_W5g(lu<pTu3^_A7n",
    "OfLm%8:EF}0V1?BSS",
    "|+E6t,AZ~XewXP17T",
    "L-nIbhm5<z:92~+,x",
    "L-nIbhm5<z:92~+,x",
    "9bC5f0q@qA(RKZ>|r",
    "9bC5f0q@qA(RKZ>|r",
    "k=5,ln(08IAl(gGAK",
    "|N,8]dGu)'^MaYpu[",
    "!&,Y*nz8C*,J}{+d]",
    "Us9%^%?n5!~e@@*+@",
    "zF8,1KV#¥]$k?|9R#",
    "0B4>=nioEjp>4rhgi",
    "EG@0[W9.N4i~E<f3x",
    "(0Pwkk&IPchJHs.7A",
    "7XgmQ6fW<|J+NY[m0",
    ".g4CwX/DU!!~!zbtZ",
    "+_U'qn_/9Fo|gT/!n",
    "=0s(mYh&F%y=MBS5(",
    "cg71(}bo+Q5P8F[T6",
    "lc|a\%5.9pOpooU+QR",
    "E_(3A:o+.]qL3MYA6",
    "H@O'X_RiVS@8l0bKD",
    "Y1gbGD`~8d>HSWN35"
};

string ReplaceLowercase(string input)
{
    for(char cChar = 'a'; cChar <= 'z'; cChar++)
    {
        size_t n = input.find(cChar, 0);
        
        string CurSub   =   Subs[cChar-97]; //  cChar-97 to get zero-based index into Subs
        
        while(n < input.length())
        {
            input.replace(n, CurSub.size(), CurSub);
        
            n   =   input.find(cChar, n+CurSub.size());
        }
    }
    
    return input;
}

int main(void)
{
    string input;
    
    cin >> input;
    
    input = ReplaceLowercase(input);
    
    cout << input << std::endl;
    cout << "encryption complete" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

> EDIT:

```
string ReplaceLowercase(string input)
{
    for(size_t pos = 0; pos<input.length(); )
    {
        char cChar  =   input[pos];
        
        if(cChar>='a' && cChar<='z')    //  it's lowercase
        {
            string CurSub   =   Subs[cChar-97]; //  cChar-97 to get zero-based index into Subs
            
            //  replace cChar with corresponding Sub
            input.replace(pos, 1, CurSub);
            
            //  Skip to the next letter in original input
            //  by jumping over newly inserted Sub
            pos +=  CurSub.length();
        }
        else    //  not lowercase, next
            pos++;
    }
    
    return input;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. maybe the question itself wasnt specific enough, but could you make it so that the code goes on to the next character of the orignal input to subsitute and not the substitution inside the already substituted string, which would create a significantly long if not infinite loop. i hope that this makes sense.

Comment: i adjusted the function so it jumps to the next letter from original input

Comment: thanks. It worked perfectly. One question though. How would I be able to encrypt a space and get the string after the space as well?

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems

1. The second argument to `std::string::replace` should be the number of characters to replace, i.e. `1`
2. You failed to test the `find` result against `std:string::npos` so it will loop indefinitely. (-1 will always be less-than string length)
3. `W.size()` is not `17`.. or is it? Either remove the stray `\` or escape it as `\\`
4. More bugs... (not a complete list. see answer by Errorist)

Furthermore, there is a ton of code repetition which could easily be avoided.

Finally, in future questions please be more specific than saying code "doesn't work."  In what ways does it not work? Tell that.